# How do I get more than 80 columns in command line mode?

Tags: command-line, display, ubuntu-minimal

I installed ubuntu from the minimalcd because I just want to use vim and command line tools.

However I would like more than 80 columns of text.  I have a large monitor so I would like at least a couple hundred columns so I can split panes in vim and have several windows open.

BTW ubuntu is installed as a VMWare Player VM.  I have already verified that the VM settings are for a large monitor; it seems that my ubuntu setup is at issue.

Answer (score 11):

The following command:

```
docker exec -e COLUMNS="`tput cols`" -e LINES="`tput lines`" -ti container bash
```

works under most, if not all circumstances.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Although your answer made me smile, it's better this way.  If you still want to add "like a boss", put it in parentheses at the end of above.  Just press [edit] to edit your answer if you want to...  (also +1 for a very good first answer)

Comment: I am not convinced that the `docker`command will work for a WM-PLAYER installation.

Comment: I like to add sassiness, thats just what I do :D @Fabby

Comment: Try it out and tell us how it went, I dont have that environment unfortunately! :) @SorenA

Answer (score 7):

The variable `$COLUMNS` specifies how wide the terminal session is; so running `COLUMNS=200` would make it 200 columns wide.

If you wanted to change that permanently you should put this in your `~/.bashrc` file which is run every time you start a terminal.

Comment: I added COLUMNS=200 to ~/.bashrc, then logged out and back in, but it didn't seem to help. I should point out that I don't even install any kind of graphical desktop, since I wanted it totally lean b/c it's in a VM on a laptop that's a few years old.  That's why I went with ubuntu minimal.  So it seems that the terminal is already started before I even have a chance to login and run my .bashrc...

Comment: In that case, it's likely that the width is determined by the `getty` program, which creates the command line interface you see on ubuntu minimal & server; I'll have a look into it

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it.  In case it is not going to be possible, and I do end up needing a desktop, I have asked another question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/219841/lightest-weight-ubuntu-desktop-for-text-editing-in-big-terminal-windows about which is the lightest weight desktop to give me what I need.

Comment: Unable to change this variable in `fish`, even when using `env`..

Comment: adding export COLUMNS=200 to ~/.bashrc worked for me

Answer (score 4):

I met about the same situation and the above answer was just what I was needed.

But in your case, here are some hints if you are still interested:

Execute: `echo $COLUMNS`. In my case is was 141. 
By manipulating with `export COLUMNS=XXX` I was indeed been able to adjust the columns amount.

And this 141 number comes from the next. 
My `.bashrc` file contains the next code:

```
# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize
```

I don't know for sure, but pretty much seems like using `shopt` command Ubuntu detects my screen resolution and sets the according number of terminal columns.
Again, setting `export COLUMNS=XXX` allows me to change this number for the current terminal window.

So in your particular case, you would have to add `export COLUMNS=200` after the quoted `shopt -s checkwinsize` or at the very end of `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 2):

Just make the terminal larger with your mouse and type:

```
sudo resize
```

### :-)

Comment: An edit and an upvote!  (I suppose this is what you meant)  If not: please [edit] and clarify!