# Increase columns or resolution - Ubuntu Server 18.04 - CLI-only - VMware ESXi 6.5

Tags: command-line, vmware, display-resolution

I am running openhabian on Ubuntu Server 18.04, hosted on VMware ESXi 6.5.  Open-VM-tools is installed and updated to its current version.

When I first run openhabian I am greeted with a [warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0yle.png), which suggests a column increase, ergo my dilemma.  I surmise that a resolution increase would help, but I seem to be stuck at 800x600 (measured against a desktop 17.04 instance).  Working on a change of $COLUMNS (also failing gain persistence) didn't work either.

There are a lot of older posts on resolution changing, none of which have worked for me.  I have modified /etc/default/grub in a variety of ways to no avail, nothing has worked, no matter my combination of changes to:

- GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
- GRUB_GFXMODE
- GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX

Upon any change, I always to a sudo update-grub and reboot to test.
I have also tried modifying [/etc/grub.d/00_header](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456527/maximum-terminal-resolution-in-ubuntu-server-virtual-box-guest) which didn't help.

On top of this, I tried a solution for changing the columns variable [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219547/how-do-i-get-more-than-80-columns-in-command-line-mode) with no luck. Although a temp change didn't seem to make the warning go away either, so I am still leaning to this being a resolution issue.

For the life of me, I can't get any of this to change, but I'm happy to try any suggestions.  Thanks!

Also, I'm fairly new to Linux, so my apologies if I have completely missed the obvious here.

Answer (score 1):

I have mostly resolved the resolution issue here... I am going to remove some of the random things I've added below to see what exactly is necessary and then retry by rolling back to a previous snap shot.  As anticipated, the resolution is proportional to $COLUMNS, with 1024x768 allowing 128.

FWIW, here is the current changes that I have in place:

1. <strike>Removed svga.guestBackedPrimaryAware = "TRUE" from .vmx file</strike>
2. <strike>Increased video ram from 4MB to 16MB per: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2152053</strike>
3. **Avoided wide-screen resolutions** (initial desire was 1280x800, I have it working at 1024x768)

   - <strike>GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="vga=792"</strike>
   - <strike>GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768</strike>
   - **GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1024x768**

*The more I edit this solution, the more I feel 'special' :)*